# Is Depo-Provera shot directly start working?

Tags: medications, prevention

Is Depo Provera shot directly start working or waiting must be required for it's effects. Secondly when the second shot should be conducted? Exactly after three months or can a delay of one to three days be acceptable or not. Or can we inject it again two to three days before the exact time?

Answer (score 1):

If the shot was given within a week of the period starting, it's instantly effective.  If not, its considered effective after 7 days.  It needs to be injected every 12-13 weeks.  Anything in that 7 day range is considered the "right" time.

https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/birth-control/birth-control-shot